# Store and query static data in log analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

While creating custom log search alerts in log analytics workspace, I want to store some data and query it in alert query. Basically, it is a mapping like ABC -> DEF, GHI -> JKL. These mappings can be changed manually.

I am looking a solution like creating a table or function in workspace, or reading data from blob in the query. I do not want to  create the table or function in the alert query, just read from it. If there are other solutions, please suggest them too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inserting custom data in Log Analytics via the REST API? This will solve your problem--and it's what we do using Runbooks. Works great.

[Log Analytics Data Collector API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but for anyone else looking to do this, see:

[Implementing Lookups in Azure Sentinel](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel-blog/implementing-lookups-in-azure-sentinel/ba-p/1091306)

> Azure Sentinel provides four methods to reference, import, and use lookup information. The methods are:

> The built-in Watchlists feature, which enables uploading CSV files as lookup tables.

> The externaldata KQL function, which enables referencing an Azure Storage file as a lookup table.

> Custom tables, imported using a custom connector.

> A KQL function utilizing the datatable operator, which can be updated interactively or using PowerShell.